# Primefaces p:remotecommand not working in IE 8

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I uses p:remoteCommand in my JSF application. I have 7 different p:remoteCommand declared to call different action in the bean. On the click on the button, these 7 remote commands are invoked at the same time. The JS function is called but the request to the server sometime is not being executed and this happen only on IE. I tested only on IE 8.

I tried to check what the error that is being return in the AJAX called but all I get is
xhr=error, status=Unknown, and error=undefined.

My function and p:remoteCommand is as followed:

```
function loadResult() {
    loadSmry();
    load1();
    load2();
    load3();
    load4();
    load5();
    load6();
}

<p:remoteCommand id="loadId" 
                 name="loadSmry"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.saveSmry}"
                 process="@this"
                 onsuccess="summaryCount=0;"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 update="logId"/>   

<p:remoteCommand id="loadId1" 
                 name="load1"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.showChrt1}"
                 onstart="showAjaxLoader('begin',1)" 
                 oncomplete="showAjaxLoader('success',1)"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 process="@this"                     
                 update="chart1" />

<p:remoteCommand id="loadId2" 
                 name="load2"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.showChrt2}"
                 onstart="showAjaxLoaderForSummary('begin',2)" 
                 oncomplete="showAjaxLoader('success',2)"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 process="@this"                     
                 update="chart2" />


<p:remoteCommand id="loadId3" 
                 name="load3"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.showChrt3}"
                 onstart="showAjaxLoader('begin',3)" 
                 oncomplete="showAjaxLoader('success',3)"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 process="@this"                     
                 update="chart3" />


<p:remoteCommand id="loadId4" 
                 name="load4"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.showChrt4}"
                 onstart="showAjaxLoader('begin',4)" 
                 oncomplete="showAjaxLoader('success',4)"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 process="@this"                     
                 update="chart4" />


<p:remoteCommand id="loadId5" 
                 name="load5"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.showChrt5}"
                 onstart="showAjaxLoader('begin',5)" 
                 oncomplete="showAjaxLoader('success',5)"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 process="@this"                     
                 update="chart5a chart5b" />

<p:remoteCommand id="loadId6" 
                 name="load6"  
                 async="true"
                 action="#{designBean.showChrt6}"
                 onstart="showAjaxLoader('begin',6)" 
                 oncomplete="showAjaxLoader('success',6)"
                 onerror="handleXhrError(xhr, status, error)"
                 process="@this"                     
                 update="chart6" />
```

Comment: any chance for nested forms ?

Comment: why those ids ? ;chart5a chart 5b; maybe ;chart5a chart5b; (without space), also , try removing commands to see which one does the troubles...

Comment: IE8 by default allows 6 concurrent connections to the same host (see http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network). Try increasing max connections per host and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are using `async="true"` on all your remote commands. Depending on the type of the bean, this may be problematic. You are trying to execute these commands in asynchronous way. If this is absolutely necessary, may answer may not help, but please change `async="true"` to `async="false"`. It is quite likely that this will solve your problem.

This issue was also reported on the primefaces [forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13580) and this helped as well.